# Incomplete upper gamma for a non-integer number of degrees of freedom

Tags: closed-form, gamma-function

I can't seem to nail the closed form of the incomplete upper gamma function for the number of degrees of freedom $s$ being a fraction type $n/2$ where $n$ is integer. For the case when $s$ is integer it's simple, wiki has the closed form.
[closed form upper incomplete gamma for integer $s$][1]

It should be simple, as we also have the value for the $\Gamma(0.5, x)$ as the starting point, but I seem to arrive to a wrong result:

$$
\Gamma(s,x) = e^{-x}s! \left(\frac{\operatorname{erfc}(\sqrt x)e^{-x}\sqrt \pi}{2} + \sqrt x + \sum_{k=0}^{s-2}\frac{x^{s-k}}{(s-k)!}\right).
$$

Help?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjGyl.png

Comment: Use http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.8.E9 and http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.4.E6

Comment: awesome! That's very helpful. What is this (a)n (imagine n is lower case) notation? It's the coefficient before the first term in 8.8.9

Comment: If you click on the "(i)" on the right, it will show you the link to the definition.

Comment: nice, Gary, thank you! The argument _z_ in the formula 8.8.9 necessarily has to be complex or it can just real value (given that it is a part of the complex space)?

Comment: Yes, it can be an real number (as you said, they are complex numbers as well). Note however that when you introduce the error function of a square root, you need to exclude non-positive numbers. From http://dlmf.nist.gov/7.6.E1 you can see that this function will have a branch point at $z=0$.

Comment: hmm thank you very much, that is indeed an important detail..

Comment: interestingly, the thing i was actually looking for all along (i.e. Q-value for the half-integer number of degrees of freedom) was explicitly listed in the source you pointed me to, on http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.4.E14.

Comment: Oh yes, I should have remembered that. I saw it a few weeks ago because of a different reason.